# iOS 11 back button issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) {

    let view = UIView()
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 70, height: 50)
    let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:-14, y: 0, width: 30, height: 27))
    btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BackArrow"), for: UIControlState());
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ExampleController.barBtnBackAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    btn.center = CGPoint(x: btn.center.x,y :view.center.y)
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ExampleController.barBtnBackAction))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(btn)
    let leftButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButtonItem
}
```

I am using this code to set back button in navigation bar in iOS 11 but it's not working good ? user has problem in tapping back button I cant use default as I want custom action with it and before iOS 11 i was using this code :- (Given Below for iOS 10) It was working fine.

```
let  barBtnNeg = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: self, action: nil)
barBtnNeg.width = -15.0
let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 27))
btn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BackArrow"), for: UIControlState());
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ExampleController.btnBackAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
let barBtnBack = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barBtnNeg, barBtnBack]
```

And if I use this code the back arrow image gets shifted towards right (alignment error) and if I decrease the x axis of the frame still image is not shifted so i have to use above code (if  #available(iOS 11, *)).

**So any solution to fix back button problem (Navigation Bar) With Custom image, Custom Selector(action) and custom alignment?**

Answer (score 1):

Add this class for navigation controller

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in self.subviews {
            let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)

            if stringFromClass.contains("BarBackground") {
                subview.frame.origin.y = -20
                subview.frame.size.height = 64
            }
        }
    }
}
```

create navigation bar where u need

```
let navigationBar = NavigationBar(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,
                                                                        y: 20),
                                                        size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width,
                                                                     height: 40)))
        navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 135.0/255.0, blue: 245.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        let button1 = UIButton()
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back"), for: UIControlState())
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector (goBack(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20)
        let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton1
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
        self.view .addSubview(navigationBar)
```